# Centroid of area drawn over a hemisphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, 3d, spherical-geometry, centroid

We were taught an theorem for finding the centroid of an arbitrary area having uniform mass density drawn over Hemisphere.

[image]

The theorem states that the centroid of and arbitrary area $A$ of uniform mass density drawn over Hemisphere is located at $\frac{B}{A}\cdot R$ distance from base of Hemisphere:

$$Y_{\text{centroid}} = \dfrac{B}{A}\times R$$

where

- $A$ is total area drawn over Sphere
- $B$ is the parallel projection of area $A$ over Base of Hemisphere
- $R$ is radius of Hemisphere.

I have verified this theorem for some symmetrical shapes drawn on Hemisphere.
My questions are:

1. Is there a **name** for this equation/theorem?
2. Is there a simple **proof** for this?

Comment: I'd probably try to use the fact that centroid is the Arithmetic Mean of all the points of a surface to try to prove the theorem.

Comment: @Blue I understand it but the problem for me is that the shape is on a sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area $A$ and its projection $B$ are given, in spherical coordinates, by:
$$
A=\int_\Omega R^2\sin\theta\, d\theta d\phi,
\quad
B=\int_\Omega R^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\, d\theta d\phi,
$$
where I took the base of the hemisphere in the $x-y$ plane, $\theta$ is the polar angle and $\Omega$ is the integration domain.

The height of the centroid is given then by its $z$ coordinates, so by definition:
$$
z_{centroid}=
{\int_\Omega R^2 z\sin\theta\, d\theta d\phi
\over
\int_\Omega R^2\sin\theta\, d\theta d\phi}=
{\int_\Omega R^2 R\cos\theta\sin\theta\, d\theta d\phi
\over
\int_\Omega R^2\sin\theta\, d\theta d\phi}=
{RB\over A}.
$$

Comment: Which "definition"?

Comment: @Blue The definition of centroid, $\frac{\int z_c dm}{\int dm}$. But still I am unfamiliar with spherical coordinates.  Will have to look up a little bit. Thank you!

Comment: @samjoe Well, that's not the definition of centroid. That's the definition of COM. You need to prove that it coincides with the centroid. :)

Comment: Yes mass is uniformly distributed so they should coincide!